# How to abstract DB access and yet support flexible filtering?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, rest, layers

I have a need to implement REST API which would support a complex filtering, so user would be able to make such requests:

```
Products?$filter=Price le 3.5 or Price gt 200
```

The API server will use a layered architecture and it will have a layer, which will abstract database access.

And here is the problem - on one hand I need to implement flexible filtering and on the other - abstract database access.

I wonder - are there proven solutions for that?

Answer (score 3):

I see no contradiction between abstracting the database and allowing complex filtering.

While you have a database layer abstraction you can still, with well defined interfaces stablish complex filtering.

In the other hand abstracting the database doesn't mean that there will not be a layer which will indeed end up dealing direcltly with the database and building up queries.

**My suggestion is that you stablish a set of methods in your API that covers the 20% of the cases that will represent the 80% of the real usage:**

```
Products?PriceRange=3.5,4.5
Products?PriceLower=3.5
Products?PriceHigher=3.5
Products?DescriptionContains=nuts
```

And combine them:

```
Products?PriceRange=3.5,4.5&DescriptionContains=nuts&Category=CANDY
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Construct a Query object, which is passed down and eventually gets
   converted into dynamic SQL in the data layer, such as in frameworks 
   like Entity Framework.
2. Or you can can have fixed queries which are complex enough to allow
   you to pass in the various filters you need.
3. Or you can have fixed queries which do the bulk of the work,
   augmented by a code layer which strips out the extra bits.

The problem with 1 is that different databases take different approaches to their query structure. You 'Abstract' one by creating interfaces etc and then you find that the structure of that abstraction does not fit well with another DB.

Additionally part of the purpose of abstracting the datalayer is to allow the various queries to be tweaked for performance. When the user can send any query they can also send slow ones.